# add / remove row from invoice page

Tags: jquery, html

Hello all I am a jquery noob, I am making a invoice page and got the add a new line to the invoice to work however when I click the remove button it will remove the first line item instead of the last. Is there a way to rename the row id when I add(clone) the first line and be able to delete the rows by the latest ones first?? heres my code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="addrow">
<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Item #1" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Qty." class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Tax" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="text" placeholder="Item Total" class="form-control" />
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='add' value='Add item' class="btn btn-success"/>
<script>
$('#add').click(function () {
var n = $('#addrow').length + 1;
var temp = $('#addrow:first').clone();
$('input:first', temp).attr('placeholder', 'Item #' + n)
$('#addrow:last').after(temp);
});
</script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="remove">Remove</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#remove").click(function(){
$("#addrow").remove();
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your code has Duplicate IDs. That is invalid HTML. You should consider changing the ID after cloning, just like you are changing the placeholder. Try with `$('.row').clone()`

Comment: any tutorials or examples can you point me to ? thanks again

Comment: If you use a common parameter like `class`, cloning, adding and deleting is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use a common parameter like `class` or `data-attrbiutes` wherever possible. Common Ids are invalid.

Check this code,

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var n = $('.row').length + 1;
    var temp = $('.row:first').clone();

    temp.attr('id', temp.attr('id') + n);       //avoiding duplicate ID

    $('input:first', temp).attr('placeholder', 'Item #' + n)
    $('.row:last').after(temp);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#remove").click(function () {
        $(".row:last").remove();               //Remove section.
    });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GfmBx/)

Comment: thanks this works perfect in the jsfiddle however I do use other rows before this html code so it duplicates those due to the .row I think thats why I was trying the #ids . if I change the row  class i think bootstrap will not like me or am I just not seeing something thanks again this jquery is cool but a little confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use my sample

[see my Code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/effectlabweb/ww1gcp0q/)

```js
var editableProducts = {

  options: {
    table: "#tableSocProducts"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this
      .setVars()
      .events();
  },
  setVars: function() {
    this.$table = $(this.options.table);
    this.$totalLines = $(this.options.table).find('tr').length - 1;
    return this;
  },
  updateLines: function() {
    var totalLines = $(this.options.table).find('tr').length - 1;
    if (totalLines <= 1) {
      $('.remove').hide();
      $('.add').show();
    }

    return this;
  },
  events: function() {
    var _self = this;

    _self.updateLines();

    this.$table
      .on('click', 'button.add', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //---------------------------------------

        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $tr.after($clone);

        if (_self.setVars().$totalLines > 1) {
          $('.remove').show();
        }

        $tr.find('.add').hide();

      })
      .on('click', 'button.remove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //---------------------------------------

        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
        $tr.remove();

        if (_self.setVars().$totalLines <= 1) {
          $('.remove').hide();
          $('.add').show();
        }
        //if have delete last button with button add visible, add another button to last tr
        if (_self.setVars().$totalLines > 1) {
          _self.$table.find('tr:last').find('.add').show();
        }

      });

    return this;
  }
};

$(function() {
  editableProducts.initialize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table" id="tableSocProducts">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-weight-semibold">Descrição</td>
        <td class="text-weight-semibold">Qtd</td>
        <td class="text-weight-semibold">Preço Unitário</td>
        <td class="text-weight-semibold">Valor Total</td>
        <td class="text-weight-semibold">#</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="">
            <button id="addNewItem" name="addNewItem" type="button" class="btn btn-success add"><i style="color:#fff" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
            <button id="removeItem" name="removeItem" type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i style="color:#fff;" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```