# add / remove row from invoice

Tags: jquery, html

Hello all I am a jquery noob, I am making a invoice page and got the add a new line to the invoice to work however the jquery code is using ".row" and I have many rows in my main page so it is causing a conflict duplicating my first row on the page. I was thinking I can give the container that my rows are in an ID and then using the DOM select the last row in the container to either delete or add a row.

```
<div class="container" id="itemrow">
    <div class="row" id="addrow">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Item #1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Qty." class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Tax" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Item Total" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type='button' id='add' value='Add item' class="btn btn-success" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="remove">Remove</button>
    <script>
        $('#add').click(function() {
            var n = $('.row').length + 1;
            var temp = $('.row:first').clone();
            temp.attr('id', temp.attr('id') + n); //avoiding duplicate ID
            $('input:first', temp).attr('placeholder', 'Item #' + n)
            $('.row:last').after(temp);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#remove").click(function() {
                $(".row:last").remove(); //Remove section.
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [add / remove row from invoice page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715028/add-remove-row-from-invoice-page)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the selector like this:

```
$(".row div:last")
```

In the case of the remove():

```
$(".row div:last").remove();
```

You have to understand how this works,
when you write .row:last, you are getting all the elements with the "row" class and then getting the last of it.

When you use ".row div:last" you are getting the element with the "row" class, then all the divs that are inside it, and then the last of those divs, which is the one you want to get.

Comment: if I have rows above and below this code outside the container wouldn't it pick those instead. Kindof the same problem

Comment: i appreciate your help. If i change the class from row to something else I believe bootstrap will go crazy any ideas

Comment: what about using nth-last-child(2) to delete one row back